# Job for httpd.service failed with no reason specified

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

i'm following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2023.html#troubleshooting-2023) guide by amazon to enable https, and
this is the command i'm trying to run:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

as you can see, i'm running into this error:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xeu httpd.service" for details.
```

to get more information, i ran this command and got this error:

```
$ systemctl status httpd.service
× httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-06-25 08:23:50 UTC; 6min ago
   Duration: 36min 11.084s
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
    Process: 29978 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 29978 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Reading configuration..."
        CPU: 46ms

Jun 25 08:23:49 ---.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 25 08:23:50 ---.ec2.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 25 08:23:50 ---.ec2.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 25 08:23:50 ---.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server.
```

i've read countless posts where people ask the same question, but in all of them there is an error described there (usually the port is already allocated, etc). but for some reason, there isn't any error (that i can find anyway) there.

more potentially useful info:

1. my os is amazon linux 2023
2. i've checked the syntax and it says
   "syntax ok"
3. when i ran the command before i did anything it worked
   (as in the beginning of the guide)

> Connect to your instance and confirm that Apache is running.
>
> [ec2-user ~]$ sudo systemctl is-enabled httpd If the returned value is
> not "enabled," start Apache and set it to start each time the system
> boots.
>
> [ec2-user ~]$ sudo systemctl start httpd && sudo systemctl enable httpd

Comment: When Apache fails, check the error_log file (or whatever name our ErrorLog file has).  If it still does not help, increase your LogLevel to see what is going on.  Once Apache itself starts correctly (using apachectl), then add systemd around it.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo journalctl -xeu httpd.service`? There might be more information in it.

Answer (score 1):

if you do according to the error output suggested to check error logs with `journalctl -xeu httpd.service` you would probably find the cause;

mine was ["httpd: Syntax error on line 358 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/laravel.conf: /etc/httpd/conf.d/laravel.conf:8: <VirtualHost> was not closed."](https://images2.imgbox.com/47/7b/L5EKTR00_o.png)

so i went and corrected the <VirtualHost> element in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/laravel.conf` file and [httpd.service is active again](https://images2.imgbox.com/9d/a8/wt7YG8ZE_o.png)